# Accessing XSD file as embedded resource in Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource

I have an XSD called SystemData.xsd which has its build action set to Embedded resource. In my Form, in the Load event, I am calling

```
this.assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

Then I am attempting to get the resource thus:

```
StreamReader schemaStream = new StreamReader( this.assembly.GetManifestResourceStream( "DataCaptureTool.UI.SystemData.xsd" ) );
```

Which is not returning anything. Am I doing this correctly? And if so, is the issue likely to be that I'm referencing the fully qualified namespace of the resource incorrectly? How can I check what this is?

Thanks

Stewart

Comment: Try reading the value of `GetManifestResourceStream` into a `Stream` object and checking it's value before calling `new StreamReader()`

Comment: The value is Null, which is the problem, the resource is not being found.

Comment: How are you including the file? Have you explicity added its data as a resource, or is it in the project with the "embed as resource" property set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having issues finding embedding resources, open the assembly in ILDASM, open the manifest and look for ".mresource" sections. These are your embedded resources. Check that you are looking for the resource using the correct name.

If you cannot find it, you have not embedded the file. Check that the "Build Action" in the properties window is "Embedded Resource".

Comment: Yep. I was not referencing it by the correct fully Qualified Namespace. It should have been UI.XSD.SystemData.xsd